# Split a para into 6 columns and place image in 3 columns using css

Tags: html, css

I have to split a para into 6 columns and place an image in 3 columns.Kindly check this,

```css
.content {
justify-content:center;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 18px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 18px;
  column-rule: 1px solid #000;

}
.inner {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 18px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 18px;
  column-rule: 1px solid #000;
  padding-bottom:50px; 
}

.img-responsive
{
display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  width:100%;
}
.content img {
   

    
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="col-md-12 outer"><div class="content">
    
   <div> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://stgimgdt.s3.amazonaws.com/Images/Article/2018/Dec/201812211135350032_Low-air-humidity-is-close-to-the-Tamil-Nadu-coastline--rain_SECVPF.gif" width="200" height="152" /></div>
    <div class=" inner"><div id="content-body-14269002-26199426" class="_yeti_done" style="display: block;">
<p>After resisting it for long, Bahujan Samaj Party supremo Mayawati has finally made her debut on social media. She has joined Twitter formally and will tweet under the handle @SushriMayawati, the party announced on Wednesday.</p><p>A website by her name is under construction.</p><p>A party statement said Ms. Mayawati decided to join the social media platform “for speedy interaction with media and masses, besides expressing her views on various important issues and national political developments”.</p><p>Ms. Mayawati’s entry into social media assumes significance ahead of the Lok Sabha elections in which she has partnered with the Samajwadi Party. SP president Akhilesh Yadav is proactive on social media and commands an impressive 8.9 million followers on Twitter.</p><p><b>Move welcomed</b></p><p>The BSP chief’s move was welcomed by many, with Rashtriya Janata Dal leader Tejashwi Yadav even taking the credit. “Happy that you acknowledged and respected my request of joining Twitter during our meeting in Lucknow on 13th January,” he tweeted.</p><p>Though the @SushriMayawati handle was registered in October 2018, the party made the official announcement only on Wednesday. She already has more than 38,000 followers.</p><p>The BSP chief's new openness to social media is in sharp contrast to her earlier position in which she dismissed the medium as being irrelevant to her cause.</p><p>Last year, she even distanced herself from some accounts running in BSP’s name, clarifying that the party had no official website, Facebook or Twitter accounts. Any such pages, accounts or sites running in the name of the BSP are “unauthorised and fake”, she had said.</p>
</div>
</div>
  </div></div></div>
```

http://previewstg.dinathanthi.org/edition.html

https://codepen.io/kamalakkanni/pen/aXLYdx

This is what I tried, but my content sequence has been changed in safari. So, can anyone pls give me different solution.
screenshot for safari output[image]

My content sequence is

all browsers                                  123456 ( correct )
safari                                       142536 ( wrong )

Can anyone please give me some other solutions(not multiple column css3) to get this layout

Thanks.

Comment: Is it Safari desktop and/or iOS? Which version? Is this dependent on the width of viewport, as text has or hasn't room under the image? What is the result (screenshot) for those that don't have Safari at the moment they check this question?

Comment: In all devices like windows safari(5.1.4),ipad safari and mac safari

Comment: Oh that's nested columns. Weird behavior from Safari, indeed! It's allowed by the spec. I tried and failed to avoid nesting with 6 columns: `column-span` is all or none-thing (`column-span: 3;` would be nice), image will overflow with `width: 300%` (per the spec) and text isn't a rectangle so no Grid layout solution…

Comment: Note: Windows Safari is a dead thing from 2011, you can forget it. This browser only exist in Apple OSes now.

Comment: in ipad ,mac also,I am getting same issue.I need to fix it.That is client's requirement